# Is the food of the type created by the synthesizer in By Any Other Name ever shown again?

Tags: star-trek-the-original-series

The crew of the Enterprise is shown eating colorful food (almost like a fruit salad at first glance) from the synthesizer which they introduce one of the Kelvans to. It is my sense that the food is what the crew eats normally (although one might have thought that the Kelvans had already modified the devices but it is clearly not the case since the crew makes no comment about a new type of food or something) but I sure don't recall seeing this in any other episode and I had thought that the food produced is just like normal food that we might eat although not derived from animals. I am pretty sure I saw a martini produced and maybe soup but that was perhaps in one of the later series, not STOS.

Is this the only example of the food of this type shown?

EDIT: I guess even though I saw all of these episodes when they first came out or in reruns, it was not until I watched online that I could observe details like this. I have no memory of this colorful food and it was only in watching this episode yesterday that I noticed this although I certainly remember the reduction of humans to the white geometric solids and the outfits the aliens wore. Seems like very diverse alien species had the same fashion designers.

Comment: Delicious Nutri-Cubes™!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### The same colorful food can be seen on more than one occasion.

For instance:

- food offered to the ambassadors in *Journey To Babel*.

[image: Journey To Babel]

- *The Conscience Of The King*

[image: The Conscience Of The King]

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer. I am betting they made this out of Playdoh.

Comment: That is the rumour. https://tinyurl.com/2p84ybue

Comment: I think they could have worked harder on this prop, made it look a lot more appealing.

Comment: @releseabe Probably not - have you ever eaten Playdoh?  It may be non-toxic but it's not particularly tasty either.  You don't want your actors grimacing with disgust after every bite of the stuff.  Some form of cake frosting (ideally fondant) would look just as good and not be so unpleasant to eat.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Not sure your point: I think the stuff could look better, its actual taste is immaterial since I doubt if the actors eat it. It is well known that prop food is rarely/never what it is supposed to be -- I think mashed potatoes were used for ice cream since they don't melt under lights. Safe to eat but probably not eaten because the scene keeps getting shot over and over often.

Comment: @releseabe Well, if they ever *did* need to show the actors eating something (which I think does happen in some scenes?), you'd want it to be something that doesn't taste terrible, since that would affect their performance.  They can *claim* on camera that those colorful globs taste like roast beef or chocolate-covered cherries or whatever else. It doesn't matter what they *actually* taste like, so long as it doesn't taste so bad it causes the actor to break character, which I'd argue that Playdoh would (by design - even if it's non-toxic, you don't want to encourage kids eating it).

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: all I am saying is, whatever they are showing us doesn't look very good. Not sure what we are arguing about.

Comment: @releseabe Oh, sorry, I think I see where the confusion was.  I was responding to your first comment that they were made out of Playdoh, not the second one about not looking appealing...

Comment: @releseabe When sci-fi presents "abstract" food like this, the implication is usually that their society is superior to ours because they have mastered their base appetites and now eat solely for sustenance rather than the visceral pleasures of consumption. I'd argue that _Star Trek_ is showing some deliberate restraint here by having their food still be roughly the same volume as real-world food instead of reducing every meal to a single, tiny pill, like so many other stories do. It is a conscious choice to make this food not look especially scrumptious.

Comment: @Tom: I disagree: I think it is a half-assed attempt to make "Space Food" look both exotic and alluring because it is so colorful. I just don't think they succeeded. I also think the food of the future will be like the best 21st century food but derived not from living animals. Our tastes were formed over many millions of years and are very big part of human pleasures.

Comment: Funny how in space they have special future sci-fi multicolor food ... and milk. Don't mess with the dairy lobby!

Comment: In the case of JtB, we can also imagine that the strange foods are appropriate for the alien species.

Comment: They are Large Marshmallows dunked in food coloring. You can even see on a couple where a person's hand got another color food coloring on the marshmallow. Notice the mostly cylindrical shape with flat top/bottom.

Comment: @SnakeDoc In the first picture, likely yes.  The second one, they're more cube-shaped, so that's probably something else.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The second one looks like real cubes of fruit - watermelon, cantaloupe, and honeydew/kiwi.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I have eaten cubic marshmallows.